# add onclick event with values from object

Tags: javascript, jquery

in the following code, why does `postCodes[i].countryCode` return the last value in the loop,
and not the current value in the loop?
and how can i return the current value in the loop?

```
for (var i = 0; i < postCodes.length; i++) {
    for (var ind = 0; ind < salesSuite.Defaults.Countries.length; ind++) {
        if (postCodes[i].countryCode == myNamespace.Countries[ind].code) {
            $('<button/>')
                .click(function () {
                    console.log(postCodes[i].countryCode);
                })
                .appendTo($modalContent);
```

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: seen that, i still dont get it.
If i add `console.log(postCodes[i].countryCode)` just after the `if` it returns the value, can someone explain what is happening here, and why?

Comment: This is a classic example of closures within a loop - read up here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/750506/448865

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a function that gets a handler which creates a local variable to hold that `postCode`. And of course the reason for this is the usage of shared variable `i` inside the handler which would have run out by the time the handler is invoked So ultimately in your handler you are trying to invoke `postCodes[postCodes.length].countryCode` which is same as `undefined.countryCode` and will throw an error..

```
$('<button/>')
     .click(getHandler(postCodes[i]))
     .appendTo($modalContent);
.....
.....

function getHandler(postCode){ 
// This function creates a closure variable postCode which will hold that particular postCode passed in for each invocation to be used in the function reference returned by this
  return function () {
        console.log(postCode.countryCode);
   }
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wrDk4/)**

Instead of doing all this you can utilize jquery data api to hold the postCode.

```
  $('<button/>')
            .click(function () {
                console.log($(this).data('postCode').countryCode);
            })
            .appendTo($modalContent).data('postCode', postCodes[i]);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/czwRV/)**

Comment: i am looking for an explanation also, could you explain this?
Why does it happen?

Comment: @Dementic Yes of course (You can read the ) by the time your handler executes on click  out the value of i will be incremented to the last value. so it will always be undefined.countrycode since `postCodes[postCodes.length+1]` is undefined.

Comment: nice way to create a closure

Comment: @A.Wolff Infact OP can use data api itself instead of complicating this much i believe.

Comment: What if i need to process an object? my example is simplified, but the `click` event should process an object.

Comment: @Dementic What?? return an object from a click handler?

Comment: @Dementic What object postCode? See my second example as well.

Comment: the object contains more data then just `postCode` e.g: postCode, countryName and so on, i need that object available in the `click` event.

Comment: @Dementic That is what you will have. You will have a `postCode` in your handler. Did you even try to apply this?

Comment: +1 you since it does work, but why do i need to seperate it to another function, cant i somehow put it inside the click event?

Comment: btw, sorry for being a pain in the ass, im just trying to figure this thing out.

Comment: @Dementic You should read about closures, this is a very good answer with a great explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work